# The font size on the mobile site for question titles in the list

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I'm considering using the mobile site instead of the app that is no longer supported, but the first thing I noticed was that I was squinting to read the question titles in the question list.

My phone is a Samsung Note 8, so the screen is on the large side, and my vision is 20/20 minus with the glasses, so I should think I would be in the range of people expected to be able to easily read the titles.

Would it be possible to get the font size closer to the easily readable size on the app?

Comment: Many of the most-used pages are now responsive, so you can often use the full-site view quite easily... have you tried it? There's a link in the footer. :) The design hasn't been optimized for mobile, though, so you may actually find the opposite problem, that titles are too big... but if you have a bigger phone, that may be good for you. :D

Comment: @Cat That's actually much better, and there are even previews, which I've lived without for years. Thanks!

Comment: Matt, also [adjust your font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Alm.png) selection and size so that it's most readable. If your current font can't be adjusted exactly where you want it choose another font that lets you pick an in-between size. You might have to try a few fonts, fiddle with the size and turn bold on/off to find the most usable combination.

Answer (score 2):

We're slowly moving away from our mobile skin towards our responsive design - "responsive" meaning that the page doesn't have a fixed minimum width and instead is designed to scale to be more usable on smaller screens like smart phones and tablets. I think this view will be better for you than the mobile view. It's more fully-functional and it looks prettier (to me, anyway) as you get to keep the per-site theming rather than the basic blue everywhere.

There are a few things to keep in mind here:

1. Not all pages are responsive yet. This includes review queues, profile pages, and many moderation-type pages. These pages will require some zooming and scrolling to get around them until we update them.
2. The responsive theme isn't optimized for mobile yet. This means that font sizes are likely too big and the content width of the page may have a lot of extra whitespace. This is also on our list of stuff to look at.

In general, even on my smaller iPhone, I find myself reaching for the full site view rather than the mobile view whenever I'm not using the app.

If you'd like to try it out, you can find the link to this view in the footer of any page. Be aware, the link is per-site, so you'll need to switch to the full-site view for each Stack Exchange Network site you use.

Comment: I find the mobile site to be useful on slow Internet connections, so in my opinion, it should be kept.